# How to set up email service with Heroku custom domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku

I just started out developing with Heroku, but stuck on how to have email service with the same domain that is pointing to Heroku services, e.g. mydomain.com -> Heroku apps.

I want to have email service with mydomain.com, perhaps, `admin@mydomain.com`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your domain name control panel you would simply create a CNAME entry for your website `www.mysite.com` to `proxy.heroku.com` and add the Heroku custom domains addon and add www.mysite.com as a named site and then you'd create MX records pointing at your mailhost - Heroku don't provide email hosting so you need to use another party. For example most of our clients we use Google Apps for mail hosting so the MX records are pointing at Google.

John.

Comment: If you will add only CNAME of www.mysite.com then the site will not be available through mysite.com. To overcome this you will have to add CNAME entry for mysite.com as well. But as soon as you add mysite.com CNAME entry the email service will stop working. Reason being CNAME has higher precedence over MX. Any workaround for this?

Comment: yes: you need dns service with ANAME records for the naked domain. so you end up: nameservers pointing to dns service, and email back to your domain provider and/or email host

Answer (score 6):

I found a good blog post that shows you how to do this using Google Apps, Heroku, and the Heroku Zerigo addon. I found this pretty useful in setting this up for an app I'm working on and it works great.

http://xtargets.com/2010/10/04/using-gmail-for-email-on-a-heroku-managed-domain/

Comment: xtargets domain expired

Answer (score 1):

In any case if you want e-mail service you should **not** setup a CNAME record for the same domain that your MX record is on, because the CNAME record will always override.